# Data Structures Singly Linked List

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, nodes, reverse

Assuming I have a head pointer H inside a singly linked list how would I accomplish this in pseudocode?
Reverse the nodes in the singly linked list pointed to by H. NOTE: No new nodes can be 
created.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it recursively by splitting the problem into the first node and the remaining nodes, reversing the remaining nodes, and then pointing the new last node to the first node. Each level's  of the recursive stack starts with the "rest" node from the level that called it

```
reverse(node header){

//Return if empty list.
if (h == null) return

//Split the problem into first and rest.
node first = header.start
node rest = first.next

//Return if only one node.
if (rest == null) return

//reverse the rest of the problem, and then point the end of the rest to the old first.
header.start = rest
reverse(header)
first.next.next = first

//Set the old first to null, as it is now the last node in the list.
first.next = null

//Point the header H to the new first node.
H.next = rest

}
```

This is simplified to not use pointers, if you can use pointers in your pseudocode, you can pass a pointer to the "rest" node to each subsequent layer of recursion.